# scipy matrix to numpy array in classification task

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy, logistic-regression

I have X_train data (class 'pandas.core.series.Series') with content

```
print(X_train)

0       WASHINGTON  —   Congressional Republicans have...
1       After the bullet shells get counted, the blood...
2       When Walt Disney’s “Bambi” opened in 1942, cri...
3       Death may be the great equalizer, but it isn’t...
4       SEOUL, South Korea  —   North Korea’s leader, ...
```

then I want to prepare data for classification:

```
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(X_train)
tfidf_transformer = TfidfTransformer()
X_train_tfidf = tfidf_transformer.fit_transform(X_train_counts)
```

and X_train_tfidf and X_train_counts now is (class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix')

But in my Logistic Regression function I can operate with numpy arrays. What should I do to fix it?

```
class LogisticRegression2:
    def __init__(self, lr=0.01, num_iter=100000, fit_intercept=True, theta=0, verbose=False):
        self.lr = lr
        self.num_iter = num_iter
        self.fit_intercept = fit_intercept
        self.theta = theta
        self.verbose = verbose

    def __add_intercept(self, X):
        intercept = np.ones((X.shape[0], 1))
        return np.concatenate((intercept, X), axis=1)

    def __sigmoid(self, z):
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-z))
        #return .5 * (1 + np.tanh(.5 * z))

    def __loss(self, h, y):
        return (-y * np.log(h) - (1 - y) * np.log(1 - h)).mean()

    def fit(self, X, y):
        if self.fit_intercept:
            X = self.__add_intercept(X)

        # weights initialization
        self.theta = np.zeros(X.shape[1])

        for i in range(self.num_iter):
            z = np.dot(X, self.theta)
            h = self.__sigmoid(z)
            gradient = np.dot(X.T, (h - y)) / y.size
            self.theta -= self.lr * gradient

            if(self.verbose == True and i % 10000 == 0):
                z = np.dot(X, self.theta)
                h = self.__sigmoid(z)
                print('loss: ', self.__loss(h, y))

    def predict_prob(self, X):
        if self.fit_intercept:
            X = self.__add_intercept(X)

        return self.__sigmoid(np.dot(X, self.theta))

    def predict(self, X, threshold=0.5):
        return self.predict_prob(X) >= threshold
```

If I use

```
X_train_dense = X_train_tfidf.toarray()

model = LogisticRegression2(lr=0.1, num_iter=100)
model.fit(X_train_dense, y_train)
preds = model.predict(X_train_dense)
```

I have have TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'str'
in

```
`gradient = np.dot(X.T, (h - y)) / y.size`
```

If i try

```
def __add_intercept(self, X):
    intercept = np.ones((X.shape[0], 1))
    return hstack((intercept, X))
```

I have memory error

Comment: `X_train_dense = X_train_tfidf.toarray()`.  `toarray` is the sparse method for creating a dense array.  `concatenate` does `np.array(X_train_tfdf)` which is wrong.  The `scipy.sparse` package documents `csr` matrices and their methods.

Comment: I try `X_train_dense = X_train_tfidf.toarray() model = LogisticRegression2(lr=0.1, num_iter=100) model.fit(X_train_dense, y_train) preds = model.predict(X_train_dense)`  and I have MemoryError

Comment: Yes, memory errors are common when trying to make a dense array from sparse ones.  That's often why code produces sparse matrices in the first place.  Does `LogisticRegression` accept sparse matrices?  or only dense arrays?

Comment: I use [it](https://medium.com/@martinpella/logistic-regression-from-scratch-in-python-124c5636b8ac) and its work fine with dense arrays. But I need to classify text too and i have sparse matrices

Comment: You can use `sparse.hstack` to add the intercept array to a sparse matrix.  The result will be a sparse matrix.

Comment: If i do `return hstack((intercept, X))`   Its not working too `model.fit(X_train_tfidf, y_train)...MemoryError`

Comment: I dont know where can be problem. If you can, please look [code](https://pastebin.com/uyFr0fYR) and data file = [test.csv](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/israelcode/test/master/test.csv)

Comment: You need to show a full stacktrace so we can identify which operation is converting the sparse matrix to dense.  I thought you were running some `scikit_learn` model, but it looks like this is your own code.  I'm not going to run code that might produce a memory error or risk hanging my computer.  I have other things to do with it besides answer SO questions.

Comment: Try [sklearn's LogisticRegression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.fit'). It supports sparse matrices out of the box.

Comment: @rvf I cant use it in my task

Comment: @hpaulj I dont know what you want, but i add more info maybe it can help you

Comment: The `TypeError` must be in `h - y`, and `y` must be a string.  It's up to you to figure out why it is a string, and what is really should be.